# TypeError takes 2 arguments Javascript Python

Tags: javascript, python, controller, odoo, rpc

I have a few codes of js which is calling from a controller in python. I am facing an error which is `createdb() takes 2 arguments, 1given`. May I know what should I put here in the function of my js here? I am still learning with javascript. Thank you for understanding.

.js

```
 $(function(){
        $("#start_trial").click(function(){
            createDatabase();
        });
    });

function createDatabase(){
        session.rpc('/custom/createdb', {
            db_name : db_name
        }).then(function() {
            console.log("Database created successfully");
            }); 
            
        }, function () {
            console.log("calling /custom/createdb caused an exception!");
        });
    }
```

.py

```
 @http.route('/custom/createdb', type='json', auth="public", methods=["POST"], website=True)
    def createdb(self, db_name):
       
        session = self._authenticate()
        if not session:
            return json.dumps(False)

        # create a new database
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        
        create_db_url = "http://localhost:8090/cus_cus/create_db"
        data = {"jsonrpc": 2.0, "params": { "name": db_name } }

        _logger.debug("Creating database...")
        r = session.post(url=create_db_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

        if r.ok:
            return json.dumps(True)
        else:
            return json.dumps(False)
```

Comment: Looks like `createdb` should be part of a class definition if you're using `self`.

Comment: May I know what should I do next? thanks for your guidance.